# How to copy values of columns from different tables (SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

I have 3 tables and in each are 2 columns:

**table1:**
field_data_field_imie 
**column:** field_imie_value **column:** entity_id

**table2:**
field_data_field_nazwisko
**column:** field_nazwisko_value **coulmn:** entity_id

**table3:**
field_data_field_nr_niu **column:** field_nr_niu_value **column:** entity_id

entity_id values are always the same in those tables. Tables are relational

I would like to write sql query to insert values from those tables to one table
I tried to make a loop but it doesnt't work

```
mysql_query("Insert INTO aplikacja1 (entity_id) SELECT entity_id FROM field_data_field_imie ");

$wynik_dystans = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM field_data_field_adres") or die('Błąd zapytania');

if(mysql_num_rows($wynik_dystans) > 0) {

    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($wynik_dystans)) {


        mysql_query("Insert INTO aplikacja1 (imie),  SELECT field_imie_value FROM field_data_field_imie WHERE entity_id = {$r['entity_id']} ");
        mysql_query("Insert INTO aplikacja1 (nazwisko) SELECT field_nazwisko_value FROM field_data_field_nazwisko WHERE entity_id = {$r['entity_id']} ");
        mysql_query("Insert INTO aplikacja1 (nr_niu) SELECT field_nr_niu_value FROM field_data_field_nr_niu WHERE entity_id = {$r['entity_id']} ");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into aplikacja1 
select 
     field_imie_value, field_nazwisko_value, field_nr_niu_value
from 
     field_data_field_imei imei, 
     field_data_field_nazwisko nazwisko, 
     field_data_field_nr_niu niu
where 
    imei.entity_id = nazwisko.entity_id
    and imei.entity_id = niu.entity_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a procedure:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/create-procedure.html

And call it with your data